# Want an optimized way to extract only few records for different categories from a table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to extract only top n(no ranking, any random order) records belonging to different categories from a single table in Snowflake. Below is the code I'm using

```
select top 100 A.col1,A.col2 from A where A.category = 'X'
union all
select top 50 A.col1,A.col2 from A where A.category = 'Y'
union all
select top 10 A.col1,A.col2 from A where A.category = 'Z'
```

I'm wondering if there is an optimized way to do this operation?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be:

```sql
with a_example as ( 
 select col1, 
        col2, 
        row_number() over(partition by category order by category) [order]
 from A
 where category in ('X','Y','Z')
) 

select col1, col2
from a_example
where [order] <= 10
```

> The syntax should not change (much) for each DBMS.